# One electron into electron-electron-positron triplet, is this possible?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-electrodynamics, scattering

Is it possible for an electron to spontaneously scattering into a positron-electron pair (via a virtual photon) and another electron? I think it isn't, since electrons don't decay. However I don't see why this would not be allowed in QED.

Answer (score 2):

This process would violate energy-momentum conservation. To see this, suppose the initial electron is at rest; then the initial energy is $E = m_ec^2$. If your proposed process happens, the final energy is at least $3 m_e c^2$, which is larger than the initial energy.

Since QED has Lorentz symmetry, the same argument applies to an initially moving electron, by boosting into its rest frame.

Comment: He asked about e-e scattering. He did erroneously refer to it as spontaneous, but I don't think he meant that.

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible for this to happen if the electron is a lone electron on not near a another charged particle. However near a charged particle momentum and energy is conserved. The electron can have an energy in excess of 1.022 Mev. This can result in a production of a gamma ray which can decay into an electron positron pair.

Comment: Note that there is a really low possibility for the gamma ray the electron created to decay into an electron positron pair.